# SGE(Sun Grid Engine) Setup and Tuning

Tags: linux, performance, server, cluster-computing, sungridengine

I am just starting setup SGE (Sun Grid Engine) for cluster.

I have two Cluster Node1 and Node2,

Each Node has 24vCPU and 240GB RAM.

Problem is looks like I don't use fully memory (Around 8%) and CPU (around 30%)

Even thought I increase Thread of program looks like every time using same resource.

I want to know there is anyway to use more memory and CPU Flexible?
And also what is starting point for this tunning.

I submit as below,

```
qsub -l mem_free=200GB -pe olcd 20 test.sh
```

I used qstat -f -j $jobid.
and get this

```
parallel environment:  olcd range: 20
usage    1:                 cpu=04:47:12, mem=30523.46624 GBs, io=0.13225, vmem=505.098M, maxvmem=3.927
```

That's looks like only one cpu is used eventhough I setup slot as 20.

I need to make performance better at least find best running time.

anyone has good idea to setup this Sun Grid Engine?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slots you reserve using qsub i.e., via the `-pe olcd 20` option, **do not** reflect what is actually used by the system. Same idea for memory, `mem_free=200GB`.

The only effect qsub/SGE has is to reserve these resources on behalf of the job.  It is up to the job to consume these resources.

Having said all this, is the job you are submitting expected to use 20 threads and 200GB of RAM?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Yes there is thread option that I can give 20 then logically use 20 CPU, But It looks like there is limitation to use CPU like 5 core per time.

Comment: What is the output of `qquota -u "*"`?

Comment: I cannot get any results

Comment: Just to be clear: 1. Your command/script actually uses 20 CPU i.e. when you run locally without qsub? 2. You request 20 slots using `-pe olcd 20` but only see CPU usage on job status of roughly 30% CPU? How do you determine number of CPUs used by the job, do login to node directly?

Comment: when I try to do qstat -f -j "job-ID" There is only one usage 1 : ~~~~

Comment: and I use top command and there are 30% CPU are use and 10% Threads are being used.

Comment: Can you please verify the question I asked above: "Your command/script actually uses 20 CPU i.e. when you run locally without qsub?"

Comment: Hi Vince Thank you for your answer I think this is because of Multiple Threading.. There are lots of Context switching if I use multiple threads